# How can I test pspell?

Tags: php, .htaccess, aspell, pspell

This was working fine then I switched to the cpanel with godaddy. If I run a test with my php info its says that pspell is enabled. Does anyone know of a way to test for errors, or even possibly a fix?

```
$pspell_config = pspell_config_create("en");
pspell_config_personal($pspell_config, "/home/user/public_html/custom.pws");
pspell_config_repl($pspell_config, "/home/user/public_html/custom.repl");
$pspell_link = pspell_new_config($pspell_config);
```

I am testing my code already with the code below.. This lets me know if it works or not but doesn't throw errors!

```
$pspell_link = pspell_new("en");
$word = "color";
if (pspell_check($pspell_link, $word)) {
echo "Found a fix.";
} else {
echo "Sorry we are working on our search engines, please bare with us!";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code to do the trick.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Call it once first because of a bug in Windows' Aspell.
pspell_new('en');

$test = pspell_new('en');

echo '
   Testing pspell.... ', pspell_check($test, 'thisisnotawordandyouknowit') ? 'failure' : 'pass', '.<br />
   If no error messages were displayed, Aspell is installed and working properly.';
```

this display errors for pspell without the need for running error checking through the php.ini